# Masonry loses layout when you hit the "back" button. Ok on refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) on this page: http://cubacreative.co.nz/

It works fine when you first visit the page, and also when you resize the browser window or flip your iPhone, as I am calling it using the following:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#content');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : 'article'
  });
});

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    parent.window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        $('#content').masonry()
    });

});
```

However, if you click on one of the boxes to go to a new page, then hit the back button, the layout is lost.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably loading a cached version of your design on your machine,  i don't get any styles in any browsers, and is probably because you're including two `<html>` tags inside of your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 


<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Properly format your markup, [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) and your page should work fine.

Edit: Noticed something else, there is no stylesheet included in your document. Since you're using wordpress there should be a `styles.css` stylesheet added to the header of your template.

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for the heads up Andres. It turns out the parent theme I am using is throwing in the extra `<html>` tags for IE. hmmmm, time for a new parent theme?!

Comment: @CarolineElisa make sure that you're including your styles.css as well, i don't see it in the header of the document.

Comment: Got it! Phew. What a mess. Just fixing the validation bugs now, then will check the site again...

Comment: Hi Andres, would you mind taking another look at the site? The HTML5 validation errors are from plugins adding `<li>` within divs (whoops) and obsolete iframe attributes. Not sure if these would be enough to stop masonry working as expected?

Comment: @CarolineElisa looks awesome now :)

Comment: Hooray! Did you try going to a project page and then hitting the back button? In Firefox the images seem to lose their heights and so the boxes overlap.

Comment: @CarolineElisa just tried it, looks perfect in FF3.6, and Chrome18.

Comment: @CarolineElisa make sure to clear your cache, it looks fine to me on FF10 on my test box.

Comment: Nope, still bad. only when I hit the back button: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B53KLf-0FHvIZm1UOU1iX09SdGE4cmRsQmRJNDJoZw

Comment: @CarolineElisa has to be something else, it looks ok for me

Comment: Ok, I guess it depends on the user settings. I know that my colleague  is having the same issue, so I am still looking to resolve it. Thanks so much for your help!